# Expose multiple apps in gcloud kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I have 2 apps running on gcloud kubernetes cluster and exposed via services. I followed steps from https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer, for serving multiple applications on load balancer.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /app1
        backend:
          serviceName: app1server
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /app2
        backend:
          serviceName: app2server
          servicePort: 8080
```

services looks like this :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1server
spec:
  ports:
  - name: app1-port
    port: 8080
  type: NodePort
----
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1server
spec:
  ports:
  - name: app2-port
    port: 8080
  type: NodePort
```

But I am getting **default backend - 404** error when I try to access http://ip/app1/test or http://ip/app2/test

Can anyone please tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: can you show `kubectl describe svc <yourService>` result? Specificaly, did it find its endpoints (and can you access it via NodePort)?

Comment: Can you access your cluster from the private network it is in? Check if the firewall allows access to your cluster from the outside. For reference: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls